# How would you put a JQuery variable inside of CSS Text Content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

thanks for checking out my question. I have looked around and can't find a way to do what I need.

I have a JQuery variable:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var test1 = "testing";
  $('#id1').text(test1);
  });
```

And I have some css:

```
@keyframes loading-text { 
  0% {
    content: "Loading";
  }
  100% {
    content: "Done";
  }
```

Is it possible to add my variable into the content? I have tried adding `<span id="id1"></span>` without luck. Here is some things I have tried. My knowledge is very basic with css content.

```
content: "Hello" <span id="id1"></span>;
content: "Hello" "<span id="id1"></span>";
content: "Hello '<span id="id1"></span>'";
```

Here is the full code if this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/ven10t4o/1/

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Since  the `content` property only works with `pseudo` elements, and you can't target `pseudo` elements with JS, you may have to reconfigure how your animation is actually working.

Comment: Shoot, I just realized this too. I will have to rewrite this is JS I guess. I am not sure where to start but I am sure I will figure it out. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this . I edited jquery and add color to span as white

```js
  $(document).ready(function($) {
  var username = "testing";
  $('.loading-text').attr("data-id1",username);
  });
```

```css
@keyframes loading-text { 
  0% {
    content:attr(data-id1) " Hello1";
  }
  30% { 
    content: attr(data-id1) " Hello 2";
  }
  35% { 
    content: attr(data-id1) " Hello 3";
  }
  60% {
    content: attr(data-id1) " Hello 4";
  }
  75% {
    content: attr(data-id1) " Hello 5";
  }
  90% {
    content: attr(data-id1) " Hello 6";
  }
    95% {
    content: attr(data-id1) " Hello 7";
  }
}

.loading-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.loading-text {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color:white;
  text-align:right;
}

.loading-text:after {
  content: attr(data-id1) " Welcome";
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation-name: loading-text;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
#id1{
  color:white;
}
.triangle {
  stroke-dasharray: 17;
  animation: dash 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.04, 0.63, 0.95) infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 136;
  }
}

.loading {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7px;
  animation: blink .9s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loading-container">
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 40 60">
    <polygon class="triangle" fill="none" stroke="#fc0303" stroke-width="1" points="16,1 32,32 1,32" />
  </svg>
  <span data-id1=""   
  class="loading-text"></span>
</div>
<div class="scss-loader"></div>
<span id="id1"></span>
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the tip, I actually have the CSS content set to white already. As this is the only place I will be using the text. But how do I add the span to  `content: "Hello";` part? Like `content: "Hello" <span id="id1"></span>;`

Comment: Do u want  to add this at final with welcome text ?

Comment: Not in final, just first lines.

Comment: Wow nice css tricks you used there, I would not have thought. I wish there was a way to tip on here, you saved me a huge hassle of having to rewrite in JS

Comment: I am happy if it solves your problem. data attributes is good way to effect css .It acts as a parameter in  css